# Testing the accuracy of the obtained confidence interval

Tags: matlab, confidence-interval

I have some random data and I obtained the bootstrap BCa intervals. Now I want to test if the obtained BCa interval does contain the true parameter 90% of the time. However, I am getting back a probability of 100%. Below is the code.

```
data = random('Poisson',4,1,10000); % pretend that the distribution is unknown
nBoots = 10000;
[bCI,~] = bootci(nBoots,{@mode,data},'alpha',0.1); %90 confidence interval

% Testing the obtained CI
CIarray = zeros(1,nBoots);
resampledMode = zeros(1,nBoots);
for i=1:nBoots
    resampledData = data(randsample(numel(data),numel(data),true));
    resampledMode(i) = mode(resampledData);
 
    if (resampledMode(i)>=bCI(1)) && (resampledMode(i)<=bCI(2))
        CIarray(i)=1;
    else
        CIarray(i)=0;
    end
end
testProb = sum(CIarray)/nBoots
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this is just caused by the fact that the mode only takes discrete values, i.e. there's an implicit rounding. If you change `mode` by `mean` you get `testProb` very close to `0.9`. By the way, there's an `ni` variable in the `if` line that should be `i`

Comment: @LuisMendo I did not think of that. I'll look into it. Thanks for pointing that out and for pointing out the error as well.

Comment: @LuisMendo I have been trying to figure out a way to circumvent the problem of rounding. This [link](http://www.helpwithnumbers.net/roundingrules) suggests some rounding rules. But I believe that the `bootci` does that for us already.